# ¿Por qué no puedo introducir registros a una tabla creada en SQLite3 con Adminer?

Tags: php, sqlite3, adminer

Mi problema es el siguiente, no se por qué Adminer no me deja almacenar registros en una tabla, no puedo almacenar nada dado que al intentarlo me retorna un error de que no tengo privilegios, que puedo hacer para tener privilegios, les dejo adjunto la imagen que lo muestra. Gracias.

[image: Estructura tabla]

[image: Error al guardar los cambios]

Este es mi código index

Comment: ¿Qué usuario estas usando? Confirma que el usuario que estés usando tenga privilegios para modificar tablas

Comment: hola si vi eso pero el usuario lo entro en blanco antes estaba con "admin" pero igual me daba ese error..., borre ese campo para que no me pida usuario e igual sigue con ese error  no encuentro linea donde se vea los privilegios...

Comment: ¿ Cual es el usuario dueño del archivo de la base de datos ? ¿ Con cual usuario se está ejecutando tu `.php` ?

Comment: El usuario es "admin", lo cambio, lo quito, igual sigue dándome ese error